# Remove Title from Table of Contents from Overleaf template

Tags: table-of-contents

For my thesis i am using the following [template](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis). Does someone know how to remove the first three titles in the TOC:

-Declaration of Authorship

-Abstract

-Acknowledgements

PS: I don't know how to create a small example code from the template without copying everything^^

Comment: Do you still want those things in the thesis itself? For each of those sections, there is a command inside them called `\addchaptertocentry`, e.g. `\addchaptertocentry{\abstractname}`. Just comment out/delete those lines from the relevant parts.

Comment: @Miradius did you find the answer useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to remove the entire declaration page simply comment out the section from the tex file in overleaf -- comment out means select the section from begindeclaration to end declaration and then press ctrl+/ which would put a percent sign in front of each line of the code thus the code will not have any effect while recompiling the document

If you only need to remove the TOC entry comment out the lines stating

```
% \addchaptertocentry{\authorshipname} % Add the declaration to the table of contents

% \addchaptertocentry{\abstractname} % Add the abstract to the table of contents

% \addchaptertocentry{\acknowledgementname} % Add the acknowledgements to the table of 
 contents
```

[image]

Abstract page
[image]
Acknowledgement page
[image]